# What circuit would I use to automatically charge a capacitor?

Tags: voltage, capacitor

I'm new at this, so I'm just trying to get certain basics right now for specific mini projects.
I'm trying to design a circuit that would automatically charge a capacitor by having a transistor turn on when the capacitor voltage reaches at or near 0 volts, then turn off only when the capacitor is fully charged and at the same voltage as the power supply.

So is there a way for a transistor to turn on when the voltage gets below a certain point, but only turn off, not just when it gets above the first point, but at a higher specific voltage?

Comment: Why don't you continuously trickle charge to the capacitor from a resistor and voltage supply. Why go to all the complexity of a voltage detection circuit?

Comment: Are you working on a switched capacitor phone charger?

Comment: Andy aka - I'm trying to learn the circuitry for recharging capacitors in an electromagnetic coilgun.